# Dell Inspiron N5050 have display problem Xubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, display

We have installed Xubuntu 16.04 in the Dell Inspiron N5050 laptop which is
showing display problem.

Ubuntu screen is showing the following message and started blinking continuously.

```
modem-manager[810]: Loaded plugin Gobi
modem-manager[810]: Loaded plugin Longcheer
modem-manager[810]: Loaded plugin ZTE
modem-manager[810]: Loaded plugin X22X
modem-manager[810]: Loaded plugin Option High-Speed
```

If any other information is needed, kindly inform.

Comment: We have windows operating system in the same laptop, which does not have this problem.

Comment: Do you use any key while this message appears? If yes this may be a cause of blinking. These messages are related to `modemmanager` package. Do you have some modems to be managed? If no, you can remove this package using `sudo apt autoremove modemmanager`. It doesn't have to do something with other OS.

Comment: @Kulfy. You are correct sir. There is a defective key present in the laptop. Hence it is pressing by itself during reboot. We believe this might be the problem.

Comment: @Kulfy We have removed modemmanager. Still display is not set.

Comment: You need to get keyboard repaired. You can wait until Ubuntu boots up. Flickering might stop

Comment: Thank you @Kulfy, we have resolved the problem by disabling the laptop keyboard. Thanks again. Soon I will replace the defective keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

The screen flickering was due to input by keyboard. We have disabled the laptop keyboard during splash using the following method:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Replaced

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

with

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.nokbd"
```

and updated the grub using the following command

```
sudo update-grub
```

After reboot the display problem solved.

Comment: Opening GUI apps with sudo is not recommended. You might like to read [Why should users never use normal sudo to start graphical applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006). I replaced gedit with nano. The results will be same.